# could not get answer for particular situaition 415 (unsupported media type) angularjs post

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

Angular service.js

```
searchUserLoginDetails: function(data) {
    console.log("in service login");
    var promise = $http({

        url: "loginuserdetailsreport/search",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        }
        /*contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",*/
      }).success(
```

JAVA spring controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "loginuserdetailsreport/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public List < Object[] > searchUserLoginDetails(@RequestBody UserLoginDetailsRequest loginDetailsRequest) {
     List < Object[] > loginUserDetailsList = new ArrayList < Object[] > ();
     log.info("user login details search ...");
```

i get hit in service till console.log, but after that it doesnot hit spring controller saying  415 (unsupported media type), please help.

Comment: what was exact change @Rakeschand ?

Comment: `415 (unsupported media type)` error occurs when there is a difference between your service call signature and AJAX request. Usually it happens for me when there is a `POST` request and if I hit the service with `GET` method

Comment: which version of jackson you are using and spring version?

Answer (score 0):

Modify you `@RequestMapping` annotation parameters to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "loginuserdetailsreport/search",consumes = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: thank u, but again giving error, 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)' @ankit MISHRA